# Regex for not allowing & sngle quotes, double quotes and should not have only numbers

Tags: regex

I have one regex for string which will not accept if string contains only number as below:

```
/(?!^\d+$)^.+$/
```

What changes need to be made in this regex so it will also fail if string contains the following special characters?

```
&,",',~,!,@
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use alternation, an or statement, like this. The parenthesis setup the conditions. The `|` character is the *or*.

```
/(^\d+$|[&"'~!@])/
```

[For more info on Regex.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/(^[\d&"'~!@]+$)/
```

Comment: This is using a negative look-ahead followed by any character from start to finish. You're still allowing the unwanted characters.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ I updated my answer. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Please edit your answer to show some sample input and output that demonstrates what your code does and an explanation of how if works. If you always include these parts you won't make the kind of mistake @AbsoluteZERO detected in your original answer because you will have tested and confirmed your answer before you post it.